# Different Patterns of Recodes Based on Level of Another Variable

Tags: r, recode

I'm working in R and I'm trying to collapse codes for variable A (turning 6 levels into 4).  I also need the recodes for A to be different at different levels of a variable B (2 levels).  So I need something like:

df$A[df$B=='1']= recode(df$A, "'1'='4'; '2'='2'; '3'='4'; '4'='3'; '5'='4'; '6'='4'")

df$A[df$B=='2']= recode(df$A, "'1'='1'; '2'='1'; '3'='1'; '4'='1'; '5'='1'; '6'='1'")

I'd like both of these to be in a new variable, C (collapsing the 6 X 2 matrix into a single 4-level factor).  I assume I could do it with a loop or function or something, but I'm new to this and don't know how to do that kind of thing.

Comment: What coding language are you trying to do this in?

Comment: Whoops, sorry.  Working in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though expected output is not mentioned in OP, it seems the need is to `recode` column `A` based on value of column `B` to prepare a fine 4-level factor.

```
# Data
df <- data.frame(A = 1:6, B = rep(2:1,3))
df
#  A B
#1 1 2
#2 2 1
#3 3 2
#4 4 1
#5 5 2
#6 6 1

#Use of which to find matching rows
index1 <- which(df$B == 1)
index2 <- which(df$B == 2)

 df$C[index1] <- recode(df$A[index1], '1'='4', '2'='2', '3'='4', '4'='3', '5'='4', '6'='4')

 df$C[index2] = recode(df$A[index2], '1'='1', '2'='1', '3'='1', '4'='1', '5'='1', '6'='1')

df
 #  A B C
 #1 1 1 4
 #2 2 2 1
 #3 3 1 4
 #4 4 2 1
 #5 5 1 4
 #6 6 2 1



> unique(df$C)
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4"
```

Comment: Awesome!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With only 2 groups you should be able to use `ifelse()`:

```
    set.seed(42)
    dfr <- data.frame(A=sample(as.character(1:6), 100, replace=TRUE), 
         B=sample(as.character(1:2), 100, replace=TRUE))
    xtabs(~A+B, dfr)
#   B
# A    1  2
#   1  5 11
#   2 12  2
#   3  6  9
#   4  5 11
#   5  9 11
#   6  7 12
    v1 <- c('4', '2', '4', '3', '4', '4')
    v2 <- c('1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')
    idx <- as.numeric(dfr$A)
    dfr$C <- ifelse(dfr$B == "1", v1[idx], v2[idx])
    xtabs(~C+A+B, dfr)
#  , , B = 1
#   A
# C    1  2  3  4  5  6
#   1  0  0  0  0  0  0
#   2  0 12  0  0  0  0
#   3  0  0  0  5  0  0
#   4  5  0  6  0  9  7

# , , B = 2

#   A
# C    1  2  3  4  5  6
#   1 11  2  9 11 11 12
#   2  0  0  0  0  0  0
#   3  0  0  0  0  0  0
#   4  0  0  0  0  0  0
```